# How to center the login form in cas overlay?

Tags: javascript, css, overlay, cas

I am new to thymeleaf and I want to customize my own login in CAS Overlay I have followed a tutorial:

> https://dacurry-tns.github.io/deploying-apereo-cas/ui_develop_update-the-login-view.html

but my house always has a suggestion on the left?
they think I should bring the css (cas.css); If so, what should be changed and how to do it?
the code used for the loginform.html is:

> https://www.codepile.net/pile/52o3by2a

and the Layout is:

> https://www.codepile.net/pile/GoPnWqyE

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have any idea about CAS but you can align your form using following way see if it works for you

add class `form-container`to your form's parent div and

```
.form-container{
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
```

```css
.form-container{
     width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Form Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="form-container"> 
    <h3>Vertical (basic) form</h3>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MaicolyMorocho if you think this help you fix your problem in some way you can marked this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. It *looks* like the Thymeleaf template you're using includes Bootstrap 4. Is that correct?

It's a bit hard to figure out exactly how to produce the results you're after since there is no live code example to view.

That said, I would try making the immediate child of your `.row` element (in the login fragment file) into a flex container itself and centering it using one of Bootstrap 4's flexbox utilities; specifically, you should add `d-flex justify-content-center` (which is Bootstrap's aliases for CSS's native `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`, respectively.

So:

```
  <main role="main" class="container mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="my-content">
          MY CONTENT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

See Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/megalofauna/pen/MWapwaO)